# how to get column value based on previous two column values in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

Hi I am new to postgrasql. I am using postgreasql version 10.1. I have a requirement to get 'Total' column value based on

1. Total = previous row 'comp_year' + previous row 'Total'
2. Total is based on id, group, year.
3. I have nearly 2 million records.
4. Need to get the resultant data set in table

[This is how my result should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xg3oX.jpg)

Below is my code its working but not able to display all the record in table grid.

Thanks in advance

```
create OR REPLACE FUNCTION TEST3() returns SETOF refcursor
    language plpgsql
as
$$
Declare
    CUMP_TOTAL INTEGER:=0;
    cur cursor for select "ID",
                       "Group",
                       "YEAR",
                       "Comp_year",
                      LAG("Comp_year") OVER (PARTITION BY "ID", "Group" ORDER BY "YEAR") AS "PRIOR_YTD1"
 from xyz"
               order by "ID","Group","YEAR" limit 1000;
C1 RECORD;
BEGIN
open cur;
loop
fetch cur INTO C1;
EXIT WHEN NOT FOUND;
IF C1."Comp_year" IS NULL THEN
    CUMP_TOTAL:=0;
ELSE
CUMP_TOTAL:=coalesce(C1."PRIOR_YTD1",0)+coalesce(CUMP_TOTAL,0);
END IF;
RAISE INFO 'Current va`enter code here`lue of parameter (%)', TOTAL ;
   RAISE notice '%',TOTAL;
  --  RETURN CUMP_TOTAL+10;
 --RAISE NOTICE 'ID             Group';
      --RETURN next C1 ||','||CUMP_TOTAL;
   -- RETURN next CUMP_TOTAL;
    --RETURN NEXT C1;
   RETURN NEXT C1."ID" ||','||C1."Group"||','||C1."YEAR"||','||coalesce(C1."Comp_year",0)||','||coalesce(TOTAL);
END LOOP;
close cur;
exception when others then
         raise notice '% %', SQLERRM, SQLSTATE;
END;
$$;
```

Comment: Welcome to the SO Community.  Please spend a few minuets to take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and review [ask]. In particular notice you are requested to not post images of data but to post as formatted test; also see [Why not post images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). Further you need to post the expected results from the test data and indicate what is wrong with the current results.

Comment: "Usually", it's not a good idea to rely on record positionning to get computations. It's iffy at best. 
A suggested solution to to create a "cheat" column for each record adding the 2 values (like called ```forward```) and then get the value of total based on ```SELECT MAX(YEAR) as last_year, forward from <table> where  YEAR < current.YEAR AND <other_fields= current.other_fields> ```